# Show $f$ is surjective $\iff f^{-1}(y)$ contains at least one element for all $y \in Y$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

Let $f: X \to Y$ be a function. Show $f$ is surjective $\iff f^{-1}(y)$ contains at least one element for all $y \in Y$.

Proof:

Let $y \in Y.$ Suppose $f^{-1}(\{y\}) = \emptyset.$ Since $f$ is surjective, there's some $x \in X$ s.t. $f(x) = y.$ This implies $f(\{x\}) = \{y\}$ meaning $y = f(x) \in f(\{x\})$. Then by definition of pre-image of set, $x \in f^{-1}(f(\{x\})) = f^{-1}(\{y\}).$ Contradiction. Now assume $x \in f^{-1}(\{y\}).$ Then by definition of inverse image of set, $f(x) \in \{y\}$ meaning $y = f(x)$. This shows $f$ is surjective.

Does the proof work? Thanks.

Comment: The proof is right, but you don't need this contradiction argument. If $f$ is surjective, given $y \in Y$ there exists $x \in X$ such that $f(x) = y$, then you can directly conclude that $f^{-1}(\{y\}) \neq \emptyset$ for all $y \in Y$.

Comment: @ABP, thank you. I have a question. Does $f(a) = f(c) = 2$ imply $f(\{a\}) = f(\{c\}) = f(\{a, c\}) = \{2\}$? Also, $f^{-1}(\{2\}) = \{a, c\}$, but $f^{-1}(\{2\}) \ne \{a\}$ and $f^{-1}(\{2\}) \ne \{c\}$. Is that correct. Just trying to get a hang of this stuff.

Comment: In general, given a set $A \subset X$, we define the image of $A$ as $f(A) = \{y \in Y; y = f(x), x \in A\}$. In this case, $f(\{a,c\}) = f(\{a\}) = f(\{c\}) = \{2\}$. The pre-image of a set $B \subset Y$ is defined by $f^{-1}(B) = \{x \in X; f(x) \in B\}$ then $\{a,c\} \subset f^{-1}(\{2\})$, but $f^{-1}(\{2\})$ also contains all the other elements  $x \in X$ such that $f(x) = 2$ so you CAN`T conclude that $\{a,c\}$ is equal to $f^{-1}(\{2\})$ unless you know the information that $a,c$ are the only elements in X such that $f(a) = f(c) = 2$.

Answer (score 2):

I would be clearer about the fact that this proof is in two parts, and which part is which. For instance by letting each part be in its own paragraph, and mark the paragraph with which part it proves

The first part, $\implies$, is fine, but smells of contradiction for the sake of contradiction. I would personally just remove the unnecessary contradiction and shorten it to something along the lines of

> $\Longrightarrow$: Let $y \in Y.$ Since $f$ is surjective, there's some $x \in X$ s.t. $f(x) = y.$ Then by definition of pre-image, $x \in f^{-1}(y).$

As for the other part, that's a bit more foggy. You want to show that $f$ is surjective, so first and foremost you want to *start* with an arbitrary $y\in Y$, and work your way towards the existence of an $x$ such that $f(x)=y$:

> $\Longleftarrow$: Let $y\in Y.$ Since $f^{-1}(y)\neq\varnothing$, there is some $x\in f^{-1}(y).$ Then by definition of pre-image, $f(x)=y$.